# Insert row with uniqueidentifier

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

This is a snippet from a stored proc that creates a database. We have a table with  uniqueidentifier PK. I'm trying to insert a row with an empty guid as the PK:

```
DECLARE @MailingListId uniqueidentifier
SET @MailingListId = (SELECT cast('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' AS uniqueidentifier))
DECLARE @MailingListName  varchar(15)
SET @MailingListName = 'General'

SET @str = ('INSERT [' + @db_name + '].[dbo].[MailingLists] ([MailingListId], [MailingListName], [Selected]) 
VALUES (' + @MailingListId + ', ''' + @MailingListName + ''', 0)')
exec (@str);
```

The error messages are

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1198
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VALUES'.
Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 1198
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')
```

Can't see what's wrong with the VALUES clause but I guess it has something to do with the final quote, although the final quote is a closing quote not an opening quote. Maybe it's the way I assign the empty guid to `@MailingListId`? Should `@MailingListId` be quoted?

Comment: Have you tried to quote `@MailingListId` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `QUOTENAME` for the database name, and proper parameters via `sp_executesql`. You can also shorten the empty guid to `CAST(0x0 AS uniqueidentifier)`

```sql
DECLARE @MailingListId uniqueidentifier = cast(0x0 AS uniqueidentifier);
DECLARE @MailingListName varchar(15) = 'General';

DECLARE @str nvarchar(max) =
N'INSERT ' + QUOTENAME(@db_name) + N'.[dbo].[MailingLists] ([MailingListId], [MailingListName], [Selected]) 
VALUES (@MailingListId,@MailingListName, 0);';

PRINT @str;  -- for debugging
exec sp_executesql
    @str,
    N'@MailingListId uniqueidentifier, @MailingListName varchar(15)',
    @MailingListId = @MailingListId, @MailingListName = @MailingListName;
```

Answer (score 1):

You debug dynamic SQL by using the `PRINT` statement to print it out - then you have static SQL to debug.

Your SQL as posted doesn't actually work, it gives an error:

> The data types varchar and uniqueidentifier are incompatible in the add operator.

Because you are trying to concatenate `@MailingListId` into your dynamic SQL string. Given that you might as well make it a string from the start.

And when inserting a `uniqueidentifier` you need to quote it, which you were doing.

```
DECLARE @db_name VARCHAR(32) = 'MyDatabase', @str NVARCHAR(MAX);

-- No point declaring as uniqueidentifier when you then have to convert back to a string to concatenate below
DECLARE @MailingListId VARCHAR(38) = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000';
DECLARE @MailingListName VARCHAR(15) = 'General';

SET @str = 'INSERT ' + QUOTENAME(@db_name) + '.[dbo].[MailingLists] ([MailingListId], [MailingListName], [Selected]) 
VALUES (''' + @MailingListId + ''', ''' + @MailingListName + ''', 0)';
--EXEC (@str);
PRINT (@str);
```

Note the use of `QUOTENAME` to protect against SQL injection.

Gives the following valid SQL:

```
INSERT [MyDatabase].[dbo].[MailingLists] ([MailingListId], [MailingListName], [Selected]) 
    VALUES ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', 'General', 0);
```

And after all that you should do it the way Charlieface suggests. But I will leave this here as you might still learn something from it.